# dynamic <a></a> doesn't run with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a web site for a photos.

Inside a dynamic div created with a jquery function (`.append`) there is this anchor:

```
<a href='#' style='color:green;' id='"+this.foto_id+"' data-id='"+this.foto_id+"' class='modificaDataFoto modificaDataFoto"+this.foto_id+"'>Modifica</a>
```

The page is load normally and if I use the browser debugger I see all the HTML code including all dynamic data from database...

But if I try to set a class of the anchor in a jquery function it doesn't run:

```
$('.modificaDataFoto').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var idFotoModifica= $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(idFotoModifica);
    $("dataFoto"+idFotoModifica).focus();
    $("dataFoto"+idFotoModifica).css("color", "red");
    $(this).attr("class", "modificaDataFotoConferma");
});
```

Why does that function not work?

Comment: Have you used the inspector to verify that the anchor has the correct ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.modificaDataFoto', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var idFotoModifica = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(idFotoModifica);
    $("dataFoto"+idFotoModifica).focus();
    $("dataFoto"+idFotoModifica).css("color", "red");
    $(this).attr("class", "modificaDataFotoConferma");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.bind()` only works on elements that are already present in the DOM. It's likely that you're trying to bind the click event to the element before the dynamic element exists.

There are two ways to fix this:

- wait until after the `<a>` element has been appended to the document before running your `$('.modificaDataFoto').bind()`, or
- Delegate the click event from a non-dynamic element (or the document itself):

```
$(document).on('click', '.modificaDataFoto', function() {
  // this is essentially the same as your existing function; I've
  // consolidated it a bit and removed the no-longer-needed preventDefault.
  $("dataFoto" + $(this).attr("data-id")).css("color", "red").focus();
  $(this).attr("class", "modificaDataFotoConferma");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood your question but if you are trying to change the element's class name then you can simply do this:

```
$( this ).switchClass( "old class", "modificaDataFotoConferma", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
```

instead of

```
 $(this).attr("class", "modificaDataFotoConferma");
```

You also have the [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

**EDIT:**

You can also use `removeClass()` and then use the `addClass()`.